# Join two tables with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join two different tables.

**document table**

```
doc_id    id_key    doc_key
A         100        11111
B         200        22222
C         300        33333
E         500        55555
```

**device table**

```
doc_id    dev_key    dev_manager
A         111       John
B         222       Smith
D         444       Jane
F         666       Sue
```

The result I want is the following

```
doc_id    id_key   doc_key   dev_key    dev_manager
A         100      11111     111        John
B         200      22222     222        Smith
C         300      33333     null       null
D         null     null      444        Jane
E         500      55555     null       null
F         null     null      666        Sue
```

doc_id may or may not exist in both tables(the value may be on one side table only.).
I used union, but it was not usable because the columns did not match. How to get the desired result?

Comment: You need to explain the logic used to create the output... what information from the records are you using to join them together?

Comment: if you are join on doc_id and want to return null on no matching keys, can't you just use full Join?

Comment: Columns don't have to be keys to be used in joins - it's just a whole lot more efficient when they are (because they're properly indexed). Have you just tried to `full join` on the `doc_id` column from each table? Along with `coalesce(document.doc_id, device.doc_id) as doc_id` in the select columns?

Answer (score 3):

```
select
  coalesce(doc.doc_id, dev.doc_id) as doc_id,
  doc.id_key,
  doc.doc_key,
  dev.dev_key,
  dev.dev_manager
from documenttable doc
full join devicetable dev on doc.doc_id = dev.doc_id
order by coalesce(doc.doc_id, dev.doc_id)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FKcZN_yj)